# Print Console table with neccessary attibute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, console-application

I have list which can be get in Entity Data Model. However there is some unnecessary attribute in the class. What can I do to ignore of these attribute when I print the data in the console table?

Comment: Don't print them, then

Comment: I get the list by one comment and use ConsoleTable.From<>().Write(); command to print the console table. So how I can do that?

Comment: What exactly is the `From` method and what exactly is the `Write` method?

Comment: Example: ConsoleTable.From<Dog>(Dogs).Write();
Where:
Dog is a name of a class
Dogs is a name of a list

Comment: if you have no access to the source code, there is no way to remove an attribute.
You can create your own data structure, copy all the data,and then you have it.

Comment: My question is what does it do, not how to use it. For example is `Write` hardcoded as `Console.WriteLine()` or can you specify where to write things to? Also what does `from` do? Does it create a ConsoleTable from a list of something?

Comment: From() will take the data of a list and create a table base on the data and the attribute in the <> class .write will print out the table